# Vim: Interactive 'Find and replace' like in atom/sublime?

Tags: vim, atom-editor

I'm currentlich switching (from atom) to vim and one of the features I miss most right now is atom's *find and replace* function. It mainly allows me to highlight a word, incrementally select matches of the string (default: ctrl-d, skipping findings: ctrl-k) and afterwards do whatever I want which is often replacing parts within all selections, creating a new line below every selection inserting stuff, etc.

Question: Is there a similar feature in vim? I'm not looking for regex-based global find and replace, I know how to do that in vim. I'm specifically looking for a some kind of *interactive* version.

thanks in advance,
Andi

EDIT

This plugin does exactly what I'm looking for (better search term: multiple cursors): https://github.com/terryma/vim-multiple-cursors

Answer (score 1):

I have zero experience with atom. However what you described could be done in vim.

You need in your config this two lines:

```
set incsearch "incremental searching
set hlsearch  "highlight match
```

Then you can just in your buffer do

- `/whatever`, you will see the incremental highlighting.
- When you finished your pattern/word, press `Enter` all matched texts will be highlighted.
- Now do a `:%s//FOO/g` all those matched text will be replaced by `FOO`.

If this is not exactly what you want, please make an example to show how it works, not everybody here use atom.

Comment: Thanks for your help! This is not quite what I want since I do not want global replacement. I want the following: Traverse interactively (via keyboard-shortcut) through all matches and select match (shortcut). Then let me do something either with the highlighted words itself or the positions the words are located at (e.g. add a line below all selections).

Comment: @A.Neumann with vim, you can do the same thing on matches (possible with confirmation), but you cannot automatically do, this match I remove it, this match I add a new line, this match... if you want that, you have to do manually by pressing `n` or `N` to locating the match.

Comment: allright, I do not want to perform separate actions on individual matches, exactly the opposite (same action on selected matches). I think in vim terms it would be 1. Find matches, 2. Select matches (Visual <something>), 3. Do something with all matches at the same time. I can traverse through the matches with n/N but I'm not able to do highlighting/visual<sth> with them. In atom cou can set _multiple cursors_ where every action you do gets executed.

Comment: Ok, explaining it brought the relevant buzzword and plugin: https://github.com/terryma/vim-multiple-cursors

Comment: @A.Neumann I don't think that plugin can do different things on different matches.

Comment: As I said, I do not to intent to do different things on my matches, in fact I want to perform the exact same actions. Don't know at which point my question/comments implied this... But thanks anyway Kent and good night